# Can I merge different edges

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces

I have a lot of edges (pictured below) and, I want to merge them all together (which in turn would create extra vertices). Is there a way to merge all of these edges?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried "limited dissolve"?

Comment: The edges at the underside crossing each other do not have shared vertices right? That's only edges going in 2 different directions, right?

Comment: @Xylvier Correct!

Comment: @Leander Yes, I've tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and the question i take it that you want to close the bottom area of the object and at the same time reduce the number of vertices to a minimum.

In that regard, i would do the following:

1. Go in **edit mode -> edge selection**
2. Select the **edges** that go along the long side ending at each side at
   the n-gon
3. Press <kbd>X</kbd> and **Delete** the **Edges**
4. Now switch to **vertex selection**
5. Select the vertices at each side at the bottom edge of the n-gon, where the previously deleted edges were connected.
6. Press <kbd>X</kbd> and **Dissolve Vertices**
7. Now the left over edges can be used to create faces along the bottom area by selecting two edges and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the area between those.

All this sounds stretched and long, but once you know the steps it's done in a jiffy.

Here a little visual of the procedure:
[image]
*I didn't go through all faces at the end, as it is just rinse and repeat.*

A tip at the end, i would suggest to use the "F2"-add-on, that comes with Blender:
[image]
*Makes it easier and faster while modeling.*

Happy Blending